# Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Element 'fieldtypes' is not supported

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

Hi I am trying to create an AssetPicker with VS 2010 it is framework 3.5 and I get the is not supported. when I deploy I can only see the fields as text.
Any Solution?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FieldTypes>
  <FieldType>
    <Field Name="TypeName">RelationshipField</Field>
    <Field Name="ParentType">Text</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeDisplayName">Relationship Field</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeShortDescription">Relationship Field</Field>
    <Field Name="FieldTypeClass">AssetPicker.RelationshipField, AssetPicker, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7498984c8afdbdb9</Field>
  </FieldType>
</FieldTypes>
```

Comment: The title is teh excact Error that VisualStudio 2010 returns. File is part of a sharepoint solution with extension .ascx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you have the file in the wrong place with the wrong name. A custom field file must be named in the format of fldtypes_*.xml (ex: fldtypes_AssetPicker.xml) and must end up in 14hive/TEMPLATE/XML.

For detailed instructions on creating custom field type using Visual Studio 2010 see:

- [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Field Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861799.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Custom field type for uploading and displaying images in SharePoint 2010 lists](http://bernado-nguyen-hoan.com/2011/11/07/walkthrough-custom-field-type-for-uploading-and-displaying-images-in-sharepoint-2010-lists/) (see step 7)